# Litle trouble with SOAP, WSDL, PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have access to web service https://www.hometownquotes.com/objects/auto.cfc?WSDL
Also I have access to https://www.hometownquotes.com/objects/test.cfc?WSDL

I try use this service:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("https://www.hometownquotes.com/objects/test.cfc?WSDL"); 
    $myArgument = '';
    $result1 = $client->myFunction($myArgument);
    var_dump($result1);
```

I recive string(3) "foo"  - I think: It's normal for test.

But, when I use real service:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("https://www.hometownquotes.com/objects/auto.cfc?WSDL"); 
    $strYear = '1981';
    $intAffiliateID = '1111';
    $strAffiliatePass = 'password';
    $result1 = $client->getMakesWS($strYear, $intAffiliateID, $strAffiliatePass);
    var_dump($result1);
```

in answer only: string(0) ""

Where problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct affiliate id and password? It seems no matter what random affiliate id and password I try, the result is always what you are getting (the nullstring). This is an indication to me that you are not using the correct credentials.